# No Such Column - When Column Exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Not sure how this is happening but it's saying the column doesn't exist:

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: element.kind: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" INNER JOIN "elements" ON "elements"."id" = "answers"."element_id" WHERE "answers"."form_id" = 55 AND "element"."kind" = 6

```
# element.rb
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

# answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :element
  belongs_to :form
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

But when I run:

```
@form.answers.joins(:element).where(:element => {:kind => 6})
```

I get the sql error above. Not sure what's going on. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

FYI I'm running rails 3.2.3 with ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: Can you add the contents of your schema.rb file? Maybe you're missing a foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is `elements` rather than `element` as generated by the query (`"element"."kind" = 6`).

```
@form.answers.joins(:elements).where(:elements => {:kind => 6})
```

I would have expected the rest of the query to be generated using the nonexistent `element` table as well, since you used `.joins(:element)` instead of `.joins(:elements)` but perhaps Rails is pluralizing inside `.joins()` for a `belongs_to` association.

```
@form.answers.joins(:element).where(:elements => {:kind => 6})
```

Comment: Nope. Since it's `belongs_to` it's just `:element`. This returned `Association named 'elements' was not found`. Thanks though.

Comment: @Marc Sorry - meant to add this initially - it's the `.where()` that is causing the problem - did you try leaving the `.join(:element)` as you already had it but pluralizing `.where(:elements)`? The SQL statement generated implies this should work.

Comment: Thanks for this post. Weird thing, the official rails guide uses plural at both places: `Client.joins(:orders).where('orders.created_at' => time_range)`, which does not work in my code.